# MSCRM 2011 CloseQuoteRequest Offline

Tags: plugins, outlook, dynamics-crm-2011, offline

I wanna close a Quote from a Plugin. Everything works fine online, but if my plugin runs offline in Outlook, i will get an error:

**Primary Key must be populated for calls to platform on rich client in offline mode**

I close the quote like that:

```
CloseQuoteRequest req = new CloseQuoteRequest();
req.QuoteClose = myQuote;
req.Value = new OptionSetValue(6);
service.Execute(req);
```

I traced my plugin while offline and my attributes like the ID of my quote are OK.

Does anyone have some ideas?

Comment: We had that issue once when adding a quote, I recall, but that was on CRM 4. And it turned out to be a bug in CRM that was fixed. Does your code work when not in off-line?

Comment: Yes, it works online. I thought its because of my Primary Field of the entity (it is subject). So i added to my quoteclose Entity the field subject. But it dont work. I have no idea whats the matter

Comment: What about `name` attribute of the quote? Maybe it's empty?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to use a late bound quoteclose entity  and provide the activityid guid:

```
var item = service.retrieve("quote",quoteid, new columnset(true);
var quoteclose = new Entity("quoteclose");


quoteclose.Attributes.Add("quoteid", item.ToEntityReference());
quoteclose.Attributes.Add("subject", "Quote Closed");
quoteclose.Attributes.Add("description", "Quote Closed");
quoteclose.Attributes.Add("quotenumber", item.Attributes["quotenumber"]);
quoteclose.Attributes.Add("ownerid", item.Attributes["ownerid"]);
quoteclose.Attributes.Add("revision", 0);
quoteclose.Attributes.Add("activityid", Guid.NewGuid());
quoteclose.Attributes.Add("actualend", DateTime.Now);

// Close the quote
CloseQuoteRequest closeQuoteRequest = new CloseQuoteRequest()
{
     QuoteClose = quoteclose,
      Status = new OptionSetValue(5)
};
contextBag.Service.Execute(closeQuoteRequest);
```